# Git commit resulting in a missing tree error

Tags: git, github, git-commit, broken-links

So I have a newly created repo and I attempted to commit my newly created code but I got an error. So I ran 'git fsck' on my repo and I got this error.

```
broken link from    tree 9da8f3ce1355d9bdf03734d42ab15e50e5cf6361
              to    tree 64a40fc17140c1ce37720675d327d59aa9105ef1
missing tree 64a40fc17140c1ce37720675d327d59aa9105ef1
```

I am new to git, so I was wondering what can I do to fix this error?

Thanks!

I looked at : [Git Missing Commit error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049603/git-missing-commit-error) and I didn't understand it.

Comment: which error did you get when you committed? and HOW did you commit?

Comment: You can try `git reflog | grep 64a40f` to see if it's still in the reflog. That might provide some more information, but as @eckes says, it depends on what error you got.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that somehow or other, one of the object files that Git uses to store the contents of your repository history has gotten lost/corrupted.

If you just recently created the repo, I'd suggest just re-creating it (or re-cloning if you cloned it from somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Use  `git add .` instead of `git add -A`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `git gc`, and then push your changes.

Referral Link: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc